# How to find last row_number in a table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Question: how to find last `row_number` in a table in SQL Server? For example, I have a table named `Employee` without any ID and don't wanna add any identity column.

```
EmpName | EmpSalary
--------+----------
Amit    | 5000
Sumit   | 4500
Ajeet   | 5600
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EmpName) row_no 
FROM
    Employee
```

but it returns this:

```
row_no
1
2
3
```

but, if 3 is the last row_no, then I want:

```
row_no
3
```

now, please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

```
With cte as
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EmpName) row_no from Employee 
)
Select max(row_no) from cte
```

Use a cte

Comment: @SiddharthaGoswami If you feel this answer helped solved your issue, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This will help the community to keep the focus on unanswered questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 row_no FROM
(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EmpName) row_no FROM Employee
)AS Emp ORDER BY row_no DESC
```